# Como alterar chart.js exibir c,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chartjs

Estou aprendendo trabalhar chartsjs trago data, com valor  janeiro com 10 clientes,  a escala fica 0.5, 1.0,1.5,2.0  eu gostaria de deichar com 1,2,3,4,... nao existe meio cliente

```
/*********************************** GRÁFICO DE LINHAS DIARIO ***********************************/
function os_dia() {
var periodoDia = $('#os_select').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        periodoDia: periodoDia
    },
    url: BASE_URL + 'home/lista_homeDia',
    success: function(resposta) {
        console.log(resposta);
        data = {
            labels: Object.keys(resposta),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'OS por Dia',
                data: ret(resposta),
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: '#80B6ED',
                backgroundColor: '#80B6ED',
                fill: false
            }]
        };
        options = {
            labels: {
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            }
        };
        Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
        var contexto = document.getElementById("graficoOsDia").getContext("2d");
        grafico = new Chart(contexto, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
    }
});
        }
     function ret(param) {
          var valores = [];
      $.each(param, function(key, val) {
    valores.push(val);
     });
     return valores;
      }



                os_dia();

             $("#os_select").change(function() {
           os_dia();
            });
```

Comment: Poderia fornecer o seu código html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um para a escala tanto do eixo X como do eixo Y

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 1
        }
    }]
}
```

Na opção `max` você escolhe o valor máximo da escala, na `min` o valor minimo, na `stepSize` é de quanto em quanto sua escala vai aumentar, no seu caso: 1.

**EDIT**: Você não precisa passar o valor `min` e `max` se não quiser, fica apenas como informação.

Você encontra mais informações aqui http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size

Espero ter ajudado!